# Java Stream Grouping By on Objects with Parent Child Relationship

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I have a class like so...

```
class Data { int id, int parent}
```

And a list of objects like so...

```
List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList();
dataList.add(new Data(1,0));
dataList.add(new Data(2,1));
dataList.add(new Data(3,1));
dataList.add(new Data(4,2));
dataList.add(new Data(5,2));
```

I want to use the streaming api to collect my list into a

```
Map<Data, List<Data>>
```

where the key of the map is the parent and the values are the children.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you don't need to alter the list later, you may use Arrays.asList(T...) to create a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collectors.groupingBy()` can give you a `Map<Integer, List<Data>>` where the key is the parent ID:

```
Map<Integer, List<Data>> map =
    dataList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getParent));
```

If you want the key to be the `Data` instance that corresponds with the parent ID, you'll need to prepare a mapping of IDs to corresponding `Data` instances first:

```
Map<Integer, Data> ids = dataList.stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Data::getID, Function.identity()));
```

and then:

```
Map<Data, List<Data>> map =
    dataList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> ids.get(d.getParent())));
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I could do it in a one liner but seems I can't. Thanks for your clear and rapid reply

Comment: @DMcg I guess it was an accident. :-D

Comment: @Eran, could you post a kotlin equivalent

Comment: @binrebin I can't. I don't know kotlin.

Comment: @Amadán, can you ?